# Sortable drag and drop across two lists (trying to follow the procedure in the example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to find a good implementation of the drag and drop across multiple lists, and I found the one on this website: https://codepen.io/gtb104/pen/GqxAH

```
$(function() {
$("#allFacets, #userFacets").sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  placeholder: "placeholder",
  delay: 150
})
.disableSelection()
.dblclick( function(e){
  var item = e.target;
  if (e.currentTarget.id === 'allFacets') {
    //move from all to user
    $(item).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(item).appendTo($('#userFacets')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  } else {
    //move from user to all
    $(item).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(item).appendTo($('#allFacets')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }
});
});
```

But I am having a problem: it seems like the code they show has missing pieces to it, for instance that the JavaScript is written to need jQuery but there is no mention of that in the html file. I have been trying to put it together in the form of the files here: https://github.com/TudorStoian/test

I get the error that:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function     (this is from the second line of the JavaScript )

I have tried to Google what this error means and where it comes from, and I've bumped into the possibility of having several jQuery objects, but that seems not to be the problem. Does anyone have any clue what's happening?

I would prefer to see a version that doesn't go beyond Vanilla JS, to cut back on dependencies in a project, but I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: If you want to see what js libraries are used in that codepen link, click on Settings at the top of the codepen page then click on JS in the modal that opens. That will show you the libraries if you want to include them. If you want to stick with vanilla JS you will have to write your own code to replicate that functionality, which will be a much bigger job. If you want to replicate that functionality I would recommend including the same libraries.

Comment: @Tim Ah, so that's where it was! I tried looking through it and I wasn't finding anything. Going to give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Tim Okay, that solved the problem! I didn't know where to find it earlier, but this works wonders, thanks a lot!